# Convert Image File Object to File Object in angular 6

Tags: python, django, angular

i'm getting image object with url address which by calling angular httpClient.get().  I stuck here about to convert image object to file object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Converting json image object to blob object

```
image_data =  this.http.get<any>(url, { responseType: 'blob' as 'json' });
```

> Converting blob object to file object

```
this.file_object = new File([image_data], 'filename', { type: 'image/jpeg', lastModified:Date.now()});
```